# Need To Hide Help and Training Option/icon in Lightning for Specific Profile

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

[image]

Need to hide Help & Training Option/Icon in lightning for specific Profile.please find the attached screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: u might hv already seen this.. but it seems there is no option to remove that..  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175489&type=1

Answer (score 1):

There is no configurable way to achieve this.

However, you can have a blank UI lightning component placed in the home page of the org. The lightning component will hide the help link from the top.

**The solution is:** The question mark link for help that you see is under a div with a class name - `oneHelpAndTrainingExperience`. So our aim should be to search for the div with class name `oneHelpAndTrainingExperience` and hide it.

**Lightning Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="OrgUtilities" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!--Its a blank UI component-->
</aura:component>
```

**JS controller:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.isHelpHidden');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS')
            {
                if(response.getReturnValue() == true)
                {
                    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('oneHelpAndTrainingExperience');
                    elements[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex class:**

```
public class OrgUtilities {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean isHelpHidden()
    {
        List<String> profileNames = new List<String>();
        /*fill up profileNames list with the profile names for which you want the help link to hide*/
        List<Profile> profileList = [Select Id from Profile where Name IN :profileNames and Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()];
        if(profileList != null && profileList.size() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Why Lightning component instead of VF?** Any VF page that you use comes from a domain `visual.force.com`, but Lightning experience opens on `lightning.force.com`, so if you try to search for a div of `lightning.force.com` domain using a script in `visual.force.com`, [Cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) occurs and it fails. So lightning component are the way out.